# How to prevent background app kill by iOS 13?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, background, kill

My app is in Xamarin forms iOS.
When I start timer to do workout and goes background after 1 or 2 minutes app is restarted instead of opening the same page.

I already added one timer that continuously running with background tasl and its working well before iOS 13.

Here is my code snippest if any one can help me to achieve it in iOS 13

```
            nint taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("BackgroundWorkTimer", OnExpiration);
            timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(2, (obj) => { });
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);

            void OnExpiration()
            {
            }
```

After adding above code it work in ios 12 and before in my AppDelegate.cs in didfinish launching method. But now in iOS 13 this is stop working.

Comment: You can't execute indefinitely in the background, nor should you need to.  You should explain what you are trying to achieve. There is probably a better and more battery-friendly way.

Comment: Yes, My app is fitness app so when user finish workout workset apps giving timer of 1 to 2 minutes for rest and then next workset,
while this rest time users are gone background to check other apps so user come back app open from scratch as ios 13 killed app from background

Comment: Well, you cannot stop the os from killing the App that's a given!

Comment: It sounds like you schedule schedule a local notification for 2 minutes after the end of the workout. iOS will then show that notification regardless of the state of your app.

Comment: Apple is always strict to background task in iOS. Try to [Registering your Apps to Run in the Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background) if your app meet the requirement.

Comment: I am wondring then How timer apps work?

Comment: Maybe they have applied for some permissions to run background tasks.

Comment: We already implemented background task and its properly working in before iOS 13 version.

Comment: This is controlled by the Apple System. Maybe something has been updated in iOS13 and from the document we can only know that you have to Register your Apps to Run in the Background.